# Bokeh dashboard error

Tags: python, bokeh

The [bokeh datashader dashboard example](https://github.com/bokeh/datashader/tree/master/examples)
crashes with the long traceback ending with this error message

```
File "dashboard/dashboard.py", line 360, in create_layout
axes_select = Select.create(name='Axes', options=axes_options)
AttributeError: type object 'Select' has no attribute 'create'
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET / (::1) 11998.72ms
```

How can I fix this?

I'm running Python-2.7 on RHEL6

Answer (score 0):

The current version of `dashboard.py` on GitHub does not have a call to `Select.create` on line 360:

https://github.com/bokeh/datashader/blob/master/examples/dashboard/dashboard.py#L360

Or anywhere else in the file. That call is a very old part of Bokeh that was removed some time last year. My best guest is that your local checkout of the Datashader repo is out of date, and needs to be updated (or you need to install older versions of Bokeh)